# Editing a Bracket Order's Stop Loss Using Woo Exchange API Results in Error

Tags: python, json, https, algorithmic-trading

I am working with the [Woo Exchange API](https://docs.woo.org/#general-information) to build an automated trading system. I've been successful in creating a Bracket order, which consists of a positional order and its associated child orders: Stop Loss and Take Profit.

The issue I am experiencing occurs when I try to [edit the Stop Loss order](https://docs.woo.org/#edit-algo-order) of the Bracket order. My Python code is using a PUT request for this purpose. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
def _generate_signature(data, API_SECRET):
    key = API_SECRET
    key_bytes = bytes(key, 'utf-8')
    data_bytes = bytes(data, 'utf-8')
    return hmac.new(key_bytes, data_bytes, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

# Getting exchange credentials
API_KEY = <api_key>
API_SECRET = <api_secret>

# timestamp in milliseconds
ts = round(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp() * 1000)

API_ENDPOINT_BASE = "http://api.woo.org/"
request_path = f'v3/algo/order/{order_id}/'  

# Request body
body = {
    "childOrders": [
        {
            "algoOrderId": stoploss_order_id,  
            "triggerPrice": str(new_stoploss),  
            "algoType": "STOP_LOSS",
            "type": "CLOSE_POSITION",
            "reduceOnly": "true",
        },
        {
            "algoOrderId": takeprofit_order_id,
            "triggerPrice": str(takeprofit),  
            "algoType": "TAKE_PROFIT",
            "type": "CLOSE_POSITION",
            "reduceOnly": "true",
        }
    ]
}

# Convert to JSON formatted string with indentation
body_str = json.dumps(body, indent=4)

# Normalize the request content
sign = f'{ts}PUT/{request_path}{body_str}'

headers = {
    'x-api-signature': _generate_signature(sign, API_SECRET),
    'x-api-timestamp': str(ts),
    'x-api-key': API_KEY,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

url = API_ENDPOINT_BASE + request_path

try:
    response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=body_str)
    response.raise_for_status()  # Raises an HTTPError if the status is 4xx, 5xx
    data = response.json()
...
```

However, when I attempt to run this code, I get the following error response: `{"success":false,"code":-1002,"message":"The request is unauthorized."}`

According to the WOO exchange API [documentation](https://docs.woo.org/#error-codes), this means: 'API key or secret is invalid, it may be because the key has insufficient permission or the key is expired/revoked.'

I've reviewed the credentials and ensured that the apikey and secret are correct and have the proper permissions. They work for placing the bracket order but I can't seem to identify the issue with editing the order.

I'm wondering if anyone has encountered this problem before or if there are any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.